# How to run a function in the background

Tags: angularjs, promise

In our AngularJS App we have some really heavy operation which can take up to 10 seconds and can be called like 30 times. In order to not block the UI we want to make that function call in the background. But I cant figure out how to do that.

I tried using `$q` like a function:

```
this.$q(resolve => {
    resolve(someHeavyCalculation())
}).then(result => stuffWeHaveToDoAfterTheCall)
```

but this blocks our program.

I tried using `$q.defered` and `setTimeout` to make the call async

```
const defered = this.$q.defered()
setTimeout(() => {
    defered.resolve(someHeavyCalculation())
})
defered.promise.then(result => stuffWeHaveToDoAfterTheCall)
```

This worked but made every other call to `$timeout` last around 8 seconds, which breaks a lot of stuff (maybe because we call that function so often?).

The last thing I tried is hoping that `$timeout` would magically lift the call into the async world

```
this.$timeout(someHeavyCalculation).then(result => stuffWeHaveToDoAfterTheCall)
```

But this didn't work either.

So what is the correct way of turning this function into a promise?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Put the calculation in a web worker. Promises may help you to handle the asynchronous results, but they don't make anything run in background.